# group_by and count number of elements in each column in R

Tags: r, group-by, aggregate, summarize

I have a data table like below:

```
city         year    t_20   t_25 
Seattle      2019    82      91  
Seattle      2018     0      103   
NYC          2010    78       8 
DC           2011    71       0  
DC           2011     0       0    
DC           2018    60       0
```

I would like to group them by `city` and `year`
and count the number of zeros in each group.

How can I do this? by `summarize_at`?

`df %>% group_by(city, year) %>% summarise_at( WHAT GOES HERE , vars(t_20:t_25))`

What should be the first argument of `summarize_at`?

or any other way? `tally`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to reshape from wide to long before `summarise`ing

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    gather(k, v, -city, -year) %>%
    group_by(city, year) %>%
    summarise(n_0 = sum(v == 0)) 
#    # A tibble: 5 x 3
## Groups:   city [?]
#  city     year   n_0
#  <fct>   <int> <int>
#1 DC       2011     3
#2 DC       2018     1
#3 NYC      2010     0
#4 Seattle  2018     1
#5 Seattle  2019     0
```

To summarise for each column separate you can do

```
df %>%
    group_by(city, year) %>%
    summarise_all(funs(sum(. == 0)))
## A tibble: 5 x 4
## Groups:   city [?]
#  city     year  t_20  t_25
#  <fct>   <int> <int> <int>
#1 DC       2011     1     2
#2 DC       2018     0     1
#3 NYC      2010     0     0
#4 Seattle  2018     1     0
#5 Seattle  2019     0     0
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "city         year    t_20   t_25
Seattle      2019    82      91
Seattle      2018     0      103
NYC          2010    78       8
DC           2011    71       0
DC           2011     0       0
DC           2018    60       0", header = T)
```

Comment: Thank you. But in your result, it is not clear how many zeros are in each column `t_20` and `t_25`.

It says for e.g. `DC       2011     3`, but I want to know how many zeros in each column exist.

Comment: I see @NoLie; in that case I misunderstood; I thought the whole exercise was to sum across all columns. To do it for every column separately is even shorter, see my update.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much indeed

Answer (score 0):

A simple group by operation lends itself well to be formulated using SQL.  For those SQL inclined, we could also try to solve this problem using the `sqldf` library:

```
library(sqldf)

sql <- "SELECT city, COUNT(CASE WHEN t_20 = 0 THEN 1 END) AS t_20_cnt,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN t_25 = 0 THEN 1 END) AS t_25_cnt
        FROM df
        GROUP BY city"

output <- sqldf(sql)
```

Comment: Could also try: `SELECT city, SUM(t_20 = 0) AS t_20_cnt,
            SUM(t_25 = 0) AS t_25_cnt ...`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I didn't know SQLite supported that syntax.  Good to know.